# rails radio buttons horizontal flexbox

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, radio-button, label, flexbox

[Click here to see form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5C3Q.jpg)

This is what I want to fix, but I'm kinda new to rails and css and I just can get the buttons to clear the labels and all stay on the same line

```css
.radio {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  label {
    display: block;
  }  
  input {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="radio">
  <%= f.label :post_type_eq, "Posts" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :post_type_eq, "post" %>
  <%= f.label :post_type_eq, "Workouts" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :post_type_eq, "workout" %>
  <%= f.label :post_type_eq, "Meals" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :post_type_eq, "meal" %>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I could not recreate the exact scenario because I do not have the code of your controller and I think it will be the same when you replace the `text_field` tags with the `radio_tags`, but let me know if you need help. Additionally I suggest you to check bootstrap and use bootstrap, as it will make it easier and quicker to build responsive websites.

You can read about the `form_for` rails tags and all his components like radio_button and text_field at the following link: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

For bootstrap check this link:
http://getbootstrap.com/

This is my final result, you can see that everything is displayed inline, i do this with css. 
I create a `div class="row"` that will include all the form_for and the inputs, this will include everything and it will have the full with of his container. So it will be look like a row.

While the labels and text_fields will only have a width of 20% of the parent container (in this case form_for which will be the full size of div class row), so in one row will fit 5 of those fields, if you choose 10% 10 elements will fit in one row. Display as block-inline allows them to stick on the same row, because block elements do not stay on the same line. For more details on css: inline/block property check this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

[image]

This is my css

```
.row { 
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    }
.col {
    widht: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is my View

```
<div class="radio row">
<%= form_for(:player) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :kingdom, "Kingdom", class: 'col' %>
  <%= f.text_field :kingdom, class: 'col' %>
  <%= f.label :kingdom, "Workouts", class: 'col' %>
  <%= f.text_field :kingdom, class: 'col' %>
  <%= f.label :kingdom, "Other", class: 'col'   %>
  <%= f.text_field :kingdom, class: 'col' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```
class GameController < ApplicationController
  def mainPage
    @post_type_eq = 1
    @array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    @player = Player.new(:kingdom => "The Roman Empire", :king => "Ceaser", :location_id => 2)
  end
  def gameSettings
    @id = params["id"].to_i
    @page = params[:page]
  end
end
```